# How to change data using platform chanel?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

I have profile data in the form of a Map. I need to pass them to the platform and return them back with a modified update date using the platform channel.
How can I change the update date and revert back?
The data should be updated on clicking the ElevatedButton.
My Flutter Page:

```js
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  static const platform = MethodChannel('samples.flutter.dev/profile');
  
  late Map<String, String> _profile = {
    'name': 'myName',
    'date of birth': 'myDate',
    'profile update date': '20.06.2022',
  };
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(_profile['name'] ?? ''),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(_profile['date of birth'] ?? ''),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(_profile['profile update date'] ?? ''),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 30),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Get Update Profile'),
              onPressed: _getUpdateProfile,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  
  Future<void> _getUpdateProfile() async {
    Map<String, String> profile;
    try {
      final int result = await platform.invokeMethod('updateProfile');
      profile = {
    'profile update date': '$result',
      };
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      profile = {
        'profile update date': '${e.message}',
      };
    }
    setState(() {
      _profile = profile;
    });
  }
}
```

My Kotlin code:

```js
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "samples.flutter.dev/profile"
   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you can return data from `method channel` like this -

```
 new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), "my_channel_name")
            .setMethodCallHandler((methodCall, result) -> {
                if (methodCall.method.equals("returnStringDataList")) {
                    // Return your List here.
                    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                    list.add("A");
                    list.add("B");
                    list.add("C");
                    result.success(list);
                }
            });

void getDataList() async {
  var channel = MethodChannel('my_channel_name');
  List<String>? list = await channel.invokeListMethod<String>('returnStringDataList');
  print(list); // [A, B, C]
}
```

Comment: What if I need to update only one value: profile update date? Not the entire Map

Comment: then retrieve it as updated string like this  result.success("updated date");
and get it like  String? updatedDate = await channel.invokeListMethod<String>('returnStringDataList');